# BigQuery: Using LAST_VALUE with an ARRAY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm hoping to use LAST_VALUE to fill missing data in a table, but the issue is, the missing data I need to fill consists of ARRAY fields. For example:

```
SELECT
  id_field,
  timestamp_field,
  LAST_VALUE(array_field) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id_field ORDER BY timestamp_field
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) AS array_field_carried
FROM table;
```

I can technically do this, but it doesn't carry down all the values in the array_field.

Any suggestions?

Here is the result I get from the code above:

| id_field | timestamp_field | array_field_carried |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 10:00:00 UTC | NULL |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 11:00:00 UTC | NULL |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 12:00:00 UTC | array value 1 |
|  |  | array value 2 |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 13:00:00 UTC | NULL |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 14:00:00 UTC | NULL |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 15:00:00 UTC | NULL |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 16:00:00 UTC | NULL |

Here is the result I expect:

| id_field | timestamp_field | array_field_carried |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 10:00:00 UTC | NULL |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 11:00:00 UTC | NULL |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 12:00:00 UTC | array value 1 |
|  |  | array value 2 |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 13:00:00 UTC | array value 1 |
|  |  | array value 2 |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 14:00:00 UTC | array value 1 |
|  |  | array value 2 |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 15:00:00 UTC | array value 1 |
|  |  | array value 2 |
| abc1 | 2023-12-01 16:00:00 UTC | array value 1 |
|  |  | array value 2 |

Comment: in the expected result, why does the first two values NULL but others values are not NULL, can you please also provide input data you are working with?

Answer (score 2):

hope this is what you need. see below query and the screenshot of the output expected.

```
WITH input_data as (
  SELECT 'abc1' as id_field , '2023-12-01 10:00:00 UTC' as timestamp_field,   null as array_field_carried
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc1' as id_field , '2023-12-01 11:00:00 UTC' as timestamp_field,   null as array_field_carried
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc1' as id_field , '2023-12-01 12:00:00 UTC' as timestamp_field,   ['array1','array2'] as array_field_carried
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc1' as id_field , '2023-12-01 13:00:00 UTC' as timestamp_field,   null as array_field_carried
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc1' as id_field , '2023-12-01 14:00:00 UTC' as timestamp_field,   null as array_field_carried
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc1' as id_field , '2023-12-01 15:00:00 UTC' as timestamp_field,   null as array_field_carried
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc1' as id_field , '2023-12-01 16:00:00 UTC' as timestamp_field,   null as array_field_carried
) SELECT *,
          IFNULL(array_field_carried,LAST_VALUE(array_field_carried IGNORE NULLS)
                  OVER (item_window ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )
          ) AS using_last_value
FROM input_data
WINDOW item_window AS (ORDER BY input_data.timestamp_field)
```

[image]